# ?android meaning

Tags: android

I've seen it used in various XML files but I can't find any actual definition of what that `?android:` does. I'm assuming it just means inherit it from the parent theme if the attribute exists in the parent theme.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes

Comment: It doesn't automatically inherit it though? Thanks though, I was misunderstanding it and confusing using values from android via @android and using the values in the attributes using ?android.

Answer (score 0):

It is used to reference a style attribute in a theme. See [Accessing resources - referencing style attributes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes)